# Using case statement within select loop

Tags: bash, shell

I am currently doing bash programming wherein I am using case statement within select loop.However,whenever I enter any input, the control goes to default case and not the case which it should actually go to.For eg. when I enter date,instead of going to date case, it goes to default case. Can anybody of you notice some error?

```
 #!/bin/bash
    select command in date pwd ls
    do
    case $command in
         date)date;;
         pwd)pwd;;
         ls)ls;;
         *)echo"wrong";;

    esac
    done
```

Comment: Btw: replace `echo"wrong"` with `echo "wrong"`.

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] when I enter date,instead of going to date case, it goes to default case.

The `select` builtin works with numbered options. You need to enter 1 for the first option "date", 2 for the second option "pwd", and so on.

The relevant parts from `help select`:

> ```
> select: select NAME [in WORDS ... ;] do COMMANDS; done
>     [...]  If the line consists of the number
>     corresponding to one of the displayed words, then NAME is set
>     to that word.  If the line is empty, WORDS and the prompt are
>     redisplayed.  If EOF is read, the command completes.  Any other
>     value read causes NAME to be set to null.  [...]
> ```